# Convert number to date format in SAS

Tags: sas

**What I have**

I have a column/variable named **Release_Date** with **length 8  format 11.** and **informat 11.**

The **observation** in that column are in the **form YYYYMMDD** SAS actually reads them as pure number

**What I want**

I want to convert those observation in DD/MM/YYYY format with format and informat as DDMMYY10.

**Example**

Release_Date is **20180612** then I want **12/06/2018**

Any help with this regard will be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you care what INFORMAT is attached to the variable? Are you planning use FS/EDIT with that dataset?  Use that dataset to read in new raw data?

Answer (score 2):

- Convert to character
- Read back in as date
- make sure the variable is different since SAS does not allow you to change a variable type

  ```
  releaseDate_NUM = input(put(Release_Date, 8. -l), yymmdd10.);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution creates a simple dataset, then processes that dataset to add the converted date:

```
data myDates;
input intDate;
datalines;
20110101
20120202
;run;

data myDates;
set myDates;
format cvtDate mmddyy10.;    * create new variable by specifying the format;
cvtDate = input(put(intDate,8.),yymmdd8.);      * assign new variable value;
run;
```

Results should be:

```
intDate   cvtDate
--------  ----------
20110101  01/01/2011
20120202  02/02/2012
```

Comment: 77mmdd should be yymmdd.